# React Node in state keep remember props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have trouble debugging this code.

I have an App component:

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  const onSelectItem = () => {
    console.log(": onSelectItem -> currentState", state);
  };

  // items is an array of ReactNode: button, when click on it. It will log the currentState.
  const items = ["FirstItem", "SecondItem"].map(item =>  (
      <button key={item} onClick={() => onSelectItem()}>
        {item}
      </button>
    );
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Menu items={items} />
      <hr />
      <button onClick={() => setState(prevState => prevState + 1)}>Change State</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My `Menu` components will receive `items` prop, and render it. It also has ability to set the active item. For simplicity's sake, I render a `button` to set activeItem to the first one. The active item will also be rendered.

```
  function Menu({ items }) {
      const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(items[0]);
      return (
        <div>
          {items}
          <hr />
          {activeItem}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Now, come to the main part:

- I press the button (before `hr`) => it shows currentState (OK)
- I press the **active button** (after `hr`) => it shows currentState (OK)
- I press change state button => the state now changes to 1 (OK)
- Now, if I press the button (before `hr` ) => It shows currentState is 1 (OK)
- But, if I press the **active button** (after `hr` ) => It still shows 0 (which is the last state) (???)

My guess is React keeps remembering everything when using `useState`. But I'm not sure. Could anyone explain this for me!

I also include the snippets for you to easily understand my problem.

```js
const {useState} = React;
function Menu({ items }) {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(items[0]);
  return (
    <div>
      {items}
      <hr />
      <span>Active Item:</span>
      {activeItem}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  console.log(state);
  const onSelectItem = () => {
    console.log(": onSelectItem -> currentState", state);
  };
  const items = ["FirstItem", "SecondItem"].map(item => {
    return (
      <button key={item} onClick={() => onSelectItem()}>
        {item}
      </button>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Menu items={items} />
      <hr />
      <button onClick={() => setState(prevState => prevState + 1)}>Change State</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the state from App component in your Menu component.

State is local to that component and can't be accessed outside, if you would like to access the state outside the component you can refer to the useContext hook implementation.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Reason you are seeing 0 in the Active state is that is the default value of useState.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass key to your menu component.

Whenever there is change in props, the component has to re-render with new props.

Refer this artcile from their official docs - https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key

Change I made is passing state as key to Menu component

```js
const {useState} = React;
function Menu({ items }) {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(items[0]);
  return (
    <div>
      {items}
      <hr />
      <span>Active Item:</span>
      {activeItem}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  console.log(state);
  const onSelectItem = () => {
    console.log(": onSelectItem -> currentState", state);
  };
  const items = ["FirstItem", "SecondItem"].map(item => {
    return (
      <button key={item} onClick={() => onSelectItem()}>
        {item}
      </button>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Menu items={items} key={state}/>
      <hr />
      <button onClick={() => setState(prevState => prevState + 1)}>Change State</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```