# ReactJs: Prop value doesn't get updated after its associated state value gets modified

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Users.js

```
class Users extends Component {
  state = {
    usersInformation: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    getAllAdmins()
      .then((retrievedAdmins) => {
        console.log("retrievedAdmins insideAPI.get(api/admin/getAllAdmin)");
        console.log(retrievedAdmins);
        this.setState({
          usersInformation: retrievedAdmins.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }

  refreshUsersList() {
    console.log("refreshUsersList is called");
    getAllAdmins()
      .then((retrievedAdmins) => {
        console.log("retrievedAdmins refreshUsersList");
        console.log(retrievedAdmins);
        this.setState({
          usersInformation: retrievedAdmins.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <UsersList
          usersInformation={this.state.usersInformation}
          pagesCount={Math.ceil(this.state.usersInformation.length / 5)}
        />
        <UsersForm refreshUsersList={this.refreshUsersList}> </UsersForm>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**UsersForm** component is responsible for creating a new user.
**UsersList** component is responsible for displaying the created users.

Once,a user is created, I call the function `refreshUsersList` in `Users` component which updates the state property `usersInformation` in the state.

```
  refreshUsersList() {
    console.log("refreshUsersList is called");
    getAllAdmins()
      .then((retrievedAdmins) => {
        console.log("retrievedAdmins refreshUsersList");
        console.log(retrievedAdmins);
        this.setState({
          usersInformation: retrievedAdmins.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
```

The property `usersInformation` is passed-on `UsersList` Component, where its values get displayed.

In the console, after the creation of a new user, I see that the `refreshUsersList` does get called succesfully and the new UsersInformation is retrieved succesfully from the database.

So `usersInformation` property in `Users` state contains the new UsersInformation.
However, the displayed `userInformation` prop in `UsersList` does not get refreshed.

So, I still have the old users values displayed.

---

**EDIT 1:**

> UsersList.js

```
class UsersList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentPage: 0,
    };

    this.handlePageClick = this.handlePageClick.bind(this);
    this.handlePreviousClick = this.handlePreviousClick.bind(this);
    this.handleNextClick = this.handleNextClick.bind(this);
  }

  handlePageClick(e, index) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      currentPage: index,
    });
  }

  handlePreviousClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1,
    });
  }

  handleNextClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Card>
          <CardHeader>
            <i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i> Admins{" "}
            <small className="text-muted">La liste complète des admins </small>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardBody>
            <Table responsive hover>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Id</th>
                  <th scope="col">Nom</th>
                  <th scope="col">Email</th>
                  <th scope="col">Role</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {this.props.usersInformation
                  .slice(
                    this.state.currentPage * 5,
                    (this.state.currentPage + 1) * 5
                  )
                  .map((userInformation) => {
                    const userLink = `/home/users/${userInformation.id}`;
                    return (
                      <tr key={userInformation.id.toString()}>
                        <td>
                          <Link to={userLink}>{userInformation.id}</Link>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <Link to={userLink}>{userInformation.nom}</Link>
                        </td>
                        <td>{userInformation.email}</td>
                        <td>{userInformation.role}</td>
                        <td>{userInformation.derniereCnx}</td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  })}
              </tbody>
            </Table>
          </CardBody>
          <Col col="6" sm="4" md="2" xl className="mb-3 mb-xl-0">
            <TablePagination
              pagesCount={this.props.pagesCount}
              currentPage={this.state.currentPage}
              handlePageClick={this.handlePageClick}
              handlePreviousClick={this.handlePreviousClick}
              handleNextClick={this.handleNextClick}
              style="color: black"
              className="bg-dark"
            />
          </Col>
        </Card>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60880350/react-node-in-state-keep-remember-props/60880911. You need to pass key to your UsersList component with length of array.

Comment: Does the `this.setState` throw an error saying `this.setState is not a function`? If so, then the `this` in your promise is not bound correctly. Another tip is to check the state using the React DevTools browser extension.

Comment: Can you add the code inside `UsersList` component?

Comment: @Ramesh I've just added it

Comment: @AliAlmohsen indeed, that was the mistake. Thank you.